# bash variable duplicated only use one instance in command

Tags: bash

In the `bash` below I am looping through the pairs of `.fastq` files and using them in the commented command. The variable `$pre` has the name in it and it does extract it, the problem that I can't figure out is how to only use it in the commented command once? In the example below `$pre` is `NA11111` but is extracted twice. Is there a way to only use it once in the command? I have tried removing duplicates with `awk` with no luck and trying `cut`. Thank you :).

**Bash**

```
 for file in /home/cmccabe/Desktop/fastq/*.fastq ; do
 sample=${file%.fastq}
 bname=`basename $sample`
 pre="$(echo $bname|cut -d- -f1,1)"

#bwa mem -M -t 16 /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/picard-tools-1.140/resources/ucsc.hg19.fasta "$sample.fastq" "$sample" /home/cmccabe/Desktop/fastq/${pre}_aln.sam
   echo "$sample.fastq"
   echo "$sample"
   echo "$pre"
   done
```

**current output**

```
/home/cmccabe/Desktop/fastq/NA11111-100ng-E08A-C06_S5_L001_R1_001.fastq   `this is $sample.fastq`
/home/cmccabe/Desktop/fastq/NA11111-100ng-E08A-C06_S5_L001_R1_001         `this is $sample`
NA11111                                                                   `this is $pre`
/home/cmccabe/Desktop/fastq/NA11111-100ng-E08A-C06_S5_L001_R2_001.fastq   `this is $sample.fastq`
/home/cmccabe/Desktop/fastq/NA11111-100ng-E08A-C06_S5_L001_R2_001         `this is $sample`
NA11111                                                                   `this is $pre`
```

**desired output**

```
#bwa mem -M -t 16 /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/picard-tools-1.140/resources/ucsc.hg19.fasta "$sample.fastq" "$sample" /home/cmccabe/Desktop/fastq/${pre}_aln.sam

$sample.fastq = /home/cmccabe/Desktop/fastq/NA11111-100ng-E08A-C06_S5_L001_R1_001.fastq
$sample = /home/cmccabe/Desktop/fastq/NA11111-100ng-E08A-C06_S5_L001_R1_001
$pre = NA11111
```

Comment: The `NA11111` value is seen in both `R1` and `R2` files.  So what logic is used to know if R1 or R2 is the file you want?  Of is once you find a file for `NA11111`, other files with `NA11111` are to be discarted?  If so, you could extract the `NA?????` values present, list the files with that prefix and keep only the first one (`head -1`).

Comment: Are you purposely trying to ignore the .fastq file with "R2" in it?

Comment: Why are you trying to do a single end alignment of a pair end experiment? Is there any reason to discard half of the data?

Comment: The `bwa` command does a paired end aliment using the R1 and R2 of the same sample but that is `NA11111` which is duplicated. Am I missing something? Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you for the catch, I think I am missing something in the command and need to modify it. This is a bit new to me, used to working with single end alignment. Thank you :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is just keep track of which items you've already seen, 
and skip the current file if it is a match.

```
declare -A seen=()

for file in /home/cmccabe/Desktop/fastq/*.fastq ; do
  sample=${file%.fastq}
  bname=$(basename "$sample")
  pre=${name%%-*}

  # Go to the next file if $pre has already been seen
  [[ -v seen[$pre] ]] && continue

  # Remember that we've now seen $pre
  seen[$pre]=

  bwa mem -M -t 16 /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/picard-tools-1.140/resources/ucsc.hg19.fasta "$sample.fastq" "$sample" "/home/cmccabe/Desktop/fastq/${pre}_aln.sam"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are trying to achieve the following:

```
for file in /home/cmccabe/Desktop/fastq/*_R1_*.fastq
do
    file2=$(echo $file | sed 's/_R1_/_R2_/')
    sample=$(basename $file .fastq | cut -d- -f1)

    bwa mem -M -t 16 -R "@RG\tID:$sample\tSM:$sample" /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/picard-tools-1.140/resources/ucsc.hg19.fasta $file $file2 > /home/cmccabe/Desktop/fastq/${sample}_aln.sam
done
```

This is, in my opinion, the best common-sense processing of your data. I made the assumtions that you will need both ends and that you will postprocess the result, so the ReadGroup line would be required.

Comment: Thank you very much @Poshi, I appreciate it :)